# Why do we get angle $\theta$ between planes by taking dot product of the normal vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, angle

Let $\theta$ be the angle between 2 planes. Then to find this angle we take the dot product of the two normal vectors to the plane, divide by their magnitudes and then finally take the $\arccos$ of the resulting value.

However, after doing this why do we not get $180 - \theta$ and rather get $\theta$ ?
[angle between two planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXJXm.png)

Comment: You can get $180-\theta$ if you take one of the vectors in the opposite direction.

Comment: okay but why do we get theta in the first place? isn't the angle between the two normal vectors 180 - theta?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "the angle between the planes." There are two angles, after all, one $\leq 90$ degrees and another $ \geq 90$ degrees. We usually take the smaller of the two, which is also the smaller of the two angles between the normal vectors.

Comment: @abc note that there are two supplementary angles that can be called "the angle between planes".   Similar to the idea of an angle between two lines.

Comment: I understand there are two supplementary angles. But if you refer to the link showing the diagram, why do we get theta rather than 180 - theta? Isn't 180 - theta the angle between the vectors considering the direction in which they are pointing. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: In the diagram, it's clear that both of the labeled angles are acute, so surely the second can't be $180 - \theta$.

Comment: @abc oh, now I understand!  Yes.  In the conventional sense, $180 - \theta$ is the angle between $\vec n_1$ and $\vec n_2$, you're right.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom okay so when i take the dot product why do I get cos(theta) rather than cos(180-theta)? Those two would have opposite signs. That is what my book and every other resource says that you should get theta by taking the dot product.

Comment: @abc To my knowledge, most resources say that you should simply use the *absolute value* of the dot product to get the cosine of the *acute* (or right) angle between planes.

Comment: @abc whether you get the positive or negative cosine directly from the dot-product depends on which normal vectors you've chosen.  For example, if we flip $\vec n_2$ in your picture, then we have two normal vectors such that the angle between them **is** really $\theta$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see. makes more sense by taking absolute value of dot product thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will get theta as the answer if you are taking the smaller angle that is the angle between 0 and 90 as you know that cos is negative in the second quadrant hence we take modulus in these cases